# Javascript save string as .csv stopped working on IE 11

Tags: javascript, csv, savefiledialog

I have been using this piece of code to export string object as a csv file on IE 11:

```
var IEwindow = window.open();
IEwindow.document.write(csvString);
IEwindow.document.close();
IEwindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, "exportedData.csv");
IEwindow.close();
```

And it was working fine for the last couple of months. Now I've noticed that since yesterday, it doesn't work anymore.

It opens the file save dialog as it used to, but it saves to .html file instead and there's no way to save it as .csv?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I've just noticed that if I add ".csv" at the end of the file name it saves it as .csv.

So I assume that I need to escape that ".csv" in the file name somehow so it's not cut off on the save file dialog?